# What is an optimal algorithm for dividing N stones into equal piles?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

What is the best known algorithm for dividing a string of arbitrary integer length into equal pieces of integer length greater than 1?

In other words if integer N is expressed in unary as N 1's, is  there an optimal algorithm for partitioning these N 1's into equal pieces all with the same number of 1's.

Comment: Do you know $N$ in advance? Because if you do, what's wrong with just division?

Comment: What do you do if $N$ is prime, so that there is no partition of $N$ into equal-size pieces? It seems as if this question is a little ill-defined.

Answer (score 2):

This is [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) of $N$.

If you allow quantum computing, then it's [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) which performs in polynomial time in $\log N$.

For classical computers, the best is the [general number field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

Notice however, that this "best" is only with respect to complexity, and algorithms like number field sieve have big $\cal O$-constants.  This means that these algorithms win for big $N$, but for small numbers or special numbers other algorithms might outperform them.

Other algorithms are elliptical curve method, Pollard's $\varrho$ method, continued fractions, etc., see for example [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms).

---

...as you are talking about *"string"* and *"computation"*, if it's about a real string in programming (a sequence of characters held in some memory), then the string is likely to be short, i.e. $N\ll2^{64}\approx 10^{21}$.

After you removed small factors from $N$ (by trial division or computing $\gcd(N,2·3·5·7·11·13·17\cdots)$) use Pollard's $\varrho$ which is easy enough to implement from scratch.  All you need is modular arithmetic over the integers.

---

Being pedantic, forming one pile of size $N$ solves the problem.

Comment: Recall that the problem asks to divide a pile of N stones -- assuming N is composite, into equal piles. Hence at least N steps are needed just to write down the answer. Could it be possible to complete the algorithm in less than N*log(N) steps? What about restrictions on space i.e. memory. Can the algorithm be carried out in less than log(N) bits of memory? Does every possible algorithm require the use of at least one arithmetic + and/or one arithmetic *?

Comment: Are you saying that writing 91 as 7·13 is not enough, and instead I'll also have to carry 91 stones around and therefore the problem is always exponential (in the length or the input)?

Comment: Yes I am restricted to working in unary and not even allowed to perform any arithmetic ops; bus only are allowed.

Comment: Yes, I am restricted to working in unary and no arithmetic ops are allowed; only bit ops.

Comment: So you are on  a Turing machine?

Comment: yes, looking for an easy algorithm that will print out in unary the concatenation u^t where say |u^t|=a Fermat Number.

Comment: Well, "easy" is quite some different criterion than "optimal".

Comment: Absolutely correct. My interest is what can be accomplished being restricted to working in Unary and only allowed the operations of bitwise addition i.e. 1+1=0, 0+1=1, 0+0=0, and non arithmetic operations like halving a bit string or reversing a bit string. I think working within binary using arithmetic operations is obscuring results that could be found being restricted to unary.